# How do I remove the space between a jumbotron and a w3 navbar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a combination of Bootstrap and W3.CSS for my test site.

[image]

As you can see, there is a white space between the navbar and jumbotron div elements, how do I remove this space? I have no padding on any of my elements.

Answer (score 1):

It's extremely difficult (almost impossible) to answer this without being able to look at the actual code used.

Here are my best guesses:

1. If you can definitely confirm you haven't used padding the likely culprit is a `margin-bottom` or `margin-top` property.
2. Check if the image used is not smaller than the div it is in. That can create blank space between it and navbar
3. Unlikely but possible: is the the image/div or navbar positioned `relative` or `absolute`? If so adjust the `top` or `bottom` values to move them vertically to close the gap
4. Is there an empty div in between the two elements? It's common practice to use a *spacer div* to add whitespace

In the future provide your code on codepen or jsfiddle so it can be examined to provide a more constructive answer.